# urlopen is very slow in the second call

Tags: python, urlopen

I use `urllib.urlopen()` in a function called `urlopen_test()`. In this function I call urlopen twice，the first call is quite fast but not the second one. Anyone call help me figure out why?

BTW, I use `line_profile` inspect every line in the function, following is the result.

## Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents

```
 5                                           @profile
 6                                           def urlopen_test():
 7         1        28690  28690.0      0.1      fh =urllib.urlopen('ftp://a.com/1.log')
 8         1           58     58.0      0.0      print fh.read()
 9
10         1     30027787 30027787.0     99.9      fh = urllib.urlopen('ftp://a.com/1.log')
11         1           40     40.0      0.0      print fh.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the point. When I call `fh.close()` after the first `fh.read()`, the `urlopen_test()` function runs fast. But I still don't understand why when I close the file returned by the first `urlopen` call the second `urlopen()` runs really fast.